# kazam / vokoscreen recording has screen flickering in the video ,why?

Tags: linux, screencasts

I tried to use Kazam / Vokoscreen to capture a screencast video, but the video end up with flickering now and then,

[snapshot of the flicking effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/815lr.jpg)

the region is rectangular and is randomly appeared anywhere in the screen.

Kazam settings is as follows: (I tried mp4/vp8 encoding, all end up with same result. I also changed framerate, still no avail.

[Kazam settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kMFI.png)

Anything wrong? 
PS:  OS Linux-Mint18 / Nvidia 740GPU

Comment: A youtube video is available  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ulkMIGc044

Comment: not only game windows, even if I capture a browser window with plain text web page scrolling up and down, it also has similar effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be the selection of capturing area.

if I use 'region' which draw a rectangular area, it will be flickering as described above.

if I use 'active window' instead, the flickering will disappear.

I guess, when selecting 'region', all relevant window that overlaying in that region including desktop will all be tracked to reflect screen content changes, flicker is due to underlaying window content being shown occasionally.

In contract, if we use only the mode 'active window' to capture ,this problem completely goes away. I guess it's because of not considering other windows stacked on the desktop.

A couple of days of research and trial, I finally get this question answered, hope that helps those who are interested.

a better video is available here.

https://youtu.be/8unxUdykReE

Comment: It looks like related to OS as well, same hardware, using different distro has different result. 

Using Kubuntu 14.04 instead of Linux Mint 18, all problems with flickering is gone.

It might be caused by distro packages.

Comment: Hello, the video is about tetris, but I ll try this out... I have also Linux Mint 18

Comment: yes the video is about tetris, it's a demonstration of the result with recording.  It's running in Virtual Machine (Windows) inside a linux OS.

Comment: i get this in kazam when capturing my entire screen. mostly firefox just flickers from waht i've seen (Manjaro/Gnome/xorg)